# Core Data context.save keeps adding records with nil cell, though such managed objects weren't added to the context

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, save

I'm writing an app that saves Movie entities using Core Data. Movie is the only entity, and there's only one attribute, name: String.

There are two view controllers. A table VC as the root of a nav bar, and an addMovie VC as a modal segue from a "+" button on the nav bar.

Problem description:
1) Fire up the app and fetch previously saved movies from database, to populate table view. This steps works ok.
2) Hit "+" button to fire addMovie VC and add a new movie. This step works ok.
3) Add movie using a textField. This is where the glitch is. The entered movie is written perfectly to the database, but a record with a nil "name" cell is also added.
4) The problem only happens when the app segues from the table VC to the addMovie VC. If you keep adding movies once in the addMovieVC, no nils are added to the database. If you go back to the table VC and again segue to the addMovie VC, the first movie you add will be recorded perfectly but accompanied by yet another movie with a nil name.

[image]

Here's my addMovieVC:

```
class AddMovieViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate
{
    var movies: [NSManagedObject] = []
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool
    {
        guard let text = textField.text else
        {
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
            return false
        }
        let trimmedText = text.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
        if trimmedText != ""
        {
            self.save(trimmedText)
            textField.text = ""
        }
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

    func save(_ name: String)
    {
        let coreDataStack = CoreDataStack()
        coreDataStack.movie.setValue(name, forKeyPath: "name")

        do
        {
            try coreDataStack.context.save()
            movies.append(coreDataStack.movie)
        } catch
        {
            print("Save error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

And this is what my Core Data stack looks like:

```
struct CoreDataStack
{
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext
    let entity: NSEntityDescription
    let movie: NSManagedObject
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>

    init()
    {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Movie", in: context)!
        movie = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: context)
        fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Movie")
        //let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name != nil")
        //fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
        fetchRequest.includesPendingChanges = false
        //fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    }
}
```

The solutions commented out on the CoreDataStack class didn't work.
Any ideas on how to get rid of nil cells? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Every time you create an instance of `CoreDataStack` you create a new `Movie`, even if you aren't going to add a movie. I suspect your problem is in your other view controller; you are creating an instance of your `CoreDataStack` to fetch the movies, but this also creates an "empty" movie.

Comment: You should only create the new managed object when you need one, not in the initialiser of `CoreDataStack`.  Also Core Data should have created a `Movie` class for you; there is no reason to use `NSManagedObject` directly

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11, you nailed it! Just fixed and everything works perfectly. If you want to post your comments as the answer, I'll be sure to upvote it. Much appreciated!